# How to add compression support to LMDB?

Tags: database, leveldb, lmdb

By default LMDB doesn't support compression .
The only cons. with LMDB it takes lots of Disk Space compared to leveldb.

So is their any way reduce the db size of LMDB by any compression methods ?

Like adding snappy compression lib ,(leveldb has inbuild snappy compression support )

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- Compress the values with whatever library suits you (e.g. snappy). This implies that you read the full value always (you don't always have to do this because the value points into a memory-map). Obviously this only helps if your values benefit from compression.
- Compress the database file with whatever library suits you. I suppose this could be a valid approach if you have databases that are seldomly accessed and you can afford to first decompress before accessing anything, probably not suitable for most usecases though.

Unfortunately lmdb doesn't support compression of i.e. it's internal pages, which would offer different tradeoffs that we can't get now without modifying lmdb itself. A pretty good overview of that can be found here: https://banksco.de/p/lmdb-the-leveldb-killer.html